# how to fix configure script for x86_64-mu-linux-gnu host toolchain prefix?

Tags: cross-compiling, configure, toolchain, gnu-toolchain

while porting [vpp](https://github.com/vpp-dev/vpp) project into [buildroot](https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot) packaging system a new/unusual/irregular host name being discovered:

```
checking host system type... x86_64-mu-linux-gnu
```

while in buildroot when x86_64 is selected, the default toolchain

```
x86_64-linux
```

is generated and symlinked into buildroot private toolchain named one

```
x86_64-buildroot-linux-uclibc
```

which is completely normal practice for cross-compilation builds.

x86_64-mu-linux-gnu is also appeared not to be a prefix for the compiler tools-set, instead, configure is looking for

```
x86_64-mu-linux-gcc, x86_64-mu-linux-gcc.br_real, x86_64-mu-linux-ar, etc
```

the question is:

what is the best practice to fix this "magic" naming (especially to get rid of central "-mu" suffix) into the regular one used inside buildroot toolchain?

would be really appreciated if something alternative to creating a set of symlinks would be proposed. (preferably fixing inside configure scripting system)

Comment: for the quick update, the file responsible for the unusual suffix generation appeared to be:

https://github.com/vpp-dev/vpp/blob/master/build-root/Makefile

where the complete unusual platform name is hardcoded on the line 179

Answer (score 0):

here is the complete original block from [Makefile](https://github.com/vpp-dev/vpp/blob/master/build-root/Makefile) had an issue about:

```
# OS to configure for.  configure --host will be set to $(ARCH)-$(OS)            
# Allow per-platform overrides                                                   

OS = $(strip $($(PLATFORM)_os))                                                  
ifeq ($(OS),)                                                                    
  OS = mu-linux                                                                  
endif
```

the solution to the problem and the reason for the irregular suffix name being discovered:

1. **vpp** is expecting you to export **PLATFORM** variable defining the architecture
   (something like: **i686**, **arm64**, **ppc64**, **x86_64**, etc)

example:

```
PLATFORM=$(ARCH)
```

2. while compiling **vpp** project cross platform way it's expecting special variable to be configured identifying OS you are going to compile for the destination platform and this identification is tricky

   - the name of the variable will be a synthesis of the arch name following by "**_os**" suffix. the value of the variable has to be OS name.
   - as for linux running on **x86_64** you have to export variable named "**x86_64_os**" with the value "**linux**" assigned.

example:

```
x86_64_os=linux
```

but it's better to export following way:

```
$(ARCH)_os=linux
```

3. resulting build command example will look something like:

   ```
   PLATFORM=$(ARCH) $(ARCH)_os=linux make bootstrap
   ```
4. in case you fail to identify OS of your toolchain the project compilation environment will define **mu-linux** as a host OS and will fail to discover toolchain corresponding.